# How to get an exception in the Scala console

Tags: scala, exception

I'd like to make the exception object thrown a val in the console that I can use.  Something like:

```
 try { ... } catch { e => make e a val }
```

so that I can do `e.toString` or the like in console.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Try`, and either match on it:

```
Try(...) match {
   case Success(value) => // do something with `value`
   case Failure(e) => // `e` is the `Throwable` that caused the operation to fail
}
```

Or if you're just messing around in the console you can force it:

```
scala> val e = Try(1/0).failed.get
e: Throwable = java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Answer (score 4):

Just don't catch it.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> ???
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  ... 33 elided

scala> lastException
res1: Throwable = scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

scala>
```

Also, more directly:

```
scala> try { ??? } catch { case e: Throwable => $intp.bind("oops", e) }
oops: Throwable = scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
res2: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IR.Result = Success

scala> oops.toString
res3: String = scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't smuggle vals out of an inner scope, which is what the body of the catch block is.  You can, however, use `scala.util.Either` to indicate that you could have either of two return values:

```
import scala.util._
val answer = try { Right(...) } catch { case e: Throwable => Left(e) }
answer match {
  case Right(r) => // Do something with the successful result r
  case Left(e) => // Do something with the exception e
}
```

Comment: Congrats on hitting six figures. You'll need a float for your rep score.

Comment: @som-snytt - I trust you'll notice if strange things start happening around 16,777,217.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget there's nothing stopping you from returning the exception, like any other value, from the catch block:

```
scala> val good = try { 1.hashCode } catch { case e: Throwable => e }
good: Any = 1

scala> val bad = try { null.hashCode } catch { case e: Throwable => e }
bad: Any = java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, you lose the type information unless you return the something of the same type in the try block:

```
scala> val badOrNull = try { null.hashCode; null } catch { case e: Throwable => e }
badOrNull: Throwable = java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In which case you're now losing the result of `try` if there's no exception.

See the other answers for more type-safe solutions like `Try` or `Either`.